# What is the purpose of this? var http = require('http')

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm super new to server-side, so apologies for such a basic question.

I was looking at an example of a Node/Express server file [in this blog post](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-real-time-twitter-stream-with-node-and-react-js) and came across this:

```
var http = require('http')
```

What is the purpose of requiring 'http'? It doesn't seem to be any kind of dependency. Is this something from Express/Node? Could someone please explain?

Comment: See here https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http

Answer (score 2):

`'http'` is a core module in node.js. 
Node.js needs to create http/https servers, hence we have to import the http module in order to create an HTTP Server.
Thus,

```
var http = require('http')
```

is just to import the built-in `http` module, so that we can create http server which will respond to our requests. After importing the module, a server can be created by using the `createServer()` method offered by `http` module.

```
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
```

For more detailed info, visit https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Answer (score 1):

You’ll use Node’s require function to use the http module. require is similar to keywords like import or include in other languages. require takes the name of a package as a string argument and returns a package. There’s nothing special about the object that’s returned—it’s often an object, but it could be a function or a string or a number.

```
var http = require('http')
```

Node has a built-in module called http. It is useful for building web applications. and by using the above code you are getting all things those are exposed by http module.

It's like creating object of a class and getting access of all the properties(Variable and Functions)of that class.

Answer (score 0):

> To use the HTTP server and client one must `require('http')`.

It is an API provided by Node.js. If you want to know more on this, https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Answer (score 0):

> It doesn't seem to be any kind of dependency

But it is. Further down in the example there's this line:

```
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(port, function() { ...
```

which requires `http` to work. You probably missed it.